# "Similar Questions" suggestions don't update after reloading draft

Tags: bug, status-bydesign

I start writing out a question, then get sidetracked, and move on to something different. Later, I come back to StackOverflow and go to write a new question, which loads the draft of my previous.

However, even after I've changed the title, tags and body to the new question, the "Similar Questions" sidebar gives me questions similar to the *previous draft* - it never updates.

Is this bug known about?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Similar Questions" sidebar items piggy-back on our draft-saving ajax calls, which occur every 45 seconds.

If all of your content has changed (especially tags), then the next draft save should update the "Similar Questions."